# VBA-Loop and fill the missing Data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a macro that loop in sheet for specific value and then fill the missing data that  are mentionned in another sheet 
the code works fine but the problem it take toooo much time to fill the missing values and sometime the excel file doesn't respond which oblige me to repeat the whole thing again

**My code :**

```
Sub TraiterNoms()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Dim i As Variant
  Dim CompareRange As Variant
  Dim x As Variant
  Dim y As Variant
  Dim derlignE As Variant
  Dim derlignC As Variant


  derlignE = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  derlignC = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set CompareRange = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A:A")

  For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i) = "" Then
      For Each x In Range("A:A")
        For Each y In CompareRange
          If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Next y
      Next x
    End If
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Anyone can light me please about Optimizing this code

Comment: For starters try calculating/creating loop invariant objects outside the loops. E.g. maybe change For Each x In Range("A:A") to For Each x in RangeA and assign RangeA before the loops. Also, good practice might be to clear those variables before exiting the macro

Comment: By using full columns you are doing at least a million million loops! Do as @GeorgeBirbilis says and limit to the used range.

Comment: I tried it , but how  should I assign RangeA before loops as e.g ?

Comment: `Set CompareRange = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A:A").resize(derlignC, 1)`

Comment: `For Each x In Range("A:A").resize(derlignE, 1)`

Comment: Thank you , it is working perfectly .